# Why the current macro will return the value of 14?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Why the printed value is 14 ?
 when I try to calculate the current macro I get this .

NOTE** this question was asked in a test.

option 1:
2+3*4++  then 2+12++ then 2+13 = 15
option 2:
2+3*4++  then 2+12++ then 2+12++ = 14 (and after print the value will raise to 15?)

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#define MACRO(x,y) x*y++   
void main()
{  
  int a=2,b=3,c=4;
  printf("%d\n",MACRO(a+b,c));
}
```

moreover I tried to put the result in a var and got the same result of 14 meaning the value  stayed 14 after print. can some explain to me why the op ++ not happening at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros perform direct substitution of the given tokens . So this:

```
MACRO(a+b,c)
```

Becomes:

```
a+b*c++
```

Because multiplication has higher precedence that addition, it gets performed first.

Best practice when working with macros is to parenthesize all arguments:

```
#define MACRO(x,y) ((x)*(y)++)
```

Then you'll get:

```
((a+b)*(c)++)
```

Which is probably what you expect.

As for the prefix `++` operator, this operator evaluates to the current value of the variable, *then* increments the variable.  Since the `++` operator is attached to `c`, that's what gets incremented.  The value of the expression doesn't change as a result, but the value of `c` is now 5.

Comment: that was a question from a test . thanks for answer so fast!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point.  Updated to reflect.

Comment: @dt170 Glad I could help.  Feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

`MACRO(a+b,c)` is expanded to `a+b*c++`

That is 2 + 3 * 4 which is 14.

At the end of the `printf`, `c` will be incremented to 5 (i.e. a *post-increment*), which you don't observe. It would have been a different matter had you written `x*++y`.

Using macros that mutate variables is a **really bad** idea: your code is *undefined* if you write, say `MACRO(a, a)`, even if you attempt to beautify your macro by enclosing the arguments in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks , usually I'm not using macros the room for errors is too big.

Answer (score 0):

It's a post increment operator.  That means that the current values is retrieved and used in computations and then the variable's value is incremented.  If you look at the value of `c` after that statement, it will be 5.  (Note the operator applies to the variable, not the result of the computation).